# Session Timeout Not Redirecting to Login Page on Expiration

Tags: session, redirect, community, timeout

I am having some issues with Session Timeouts not redirecting Community users to the login page as defined in the session setting. According to Salesforce definition of the setting, it is to expire the session and return users to the login page. However, I am not seeing this behavior with our Community users at all. I am curious if there is a limitation with this within a Community with a custom login page that i am not aware of. Browsers are currently **NOT** redirecting to the login page and are simply sitting on whatever page they timeout out on.

Will I need to monitor session times myself and perform my own redirects/refreshes, or is there something I'm missing here that would be causing the undesired behavior?

[image]

> Requires that when sessions time out for inactive users, current sessions become invalid. Browsers are automatically refreshed and return to the login page. To access the organization again when this occurs, users must log in again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who ends up on this question, or with this issue, Salesforce has confirmed this as a bug with Communities and has escalated on their end for a resolution in a next release.

> [Session lockout time passes but community user is not logged out automatically](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YHr)

Note that if you are exposing anything "sensitive" through your Community and need to actually have session timeouts refresh browsers and redirect to your login screen, you will need to solve this with an alternative solution for the time being. We just threw [timeout-dialog.js](http://rigoneri.github.io/timeout-dialog.js/) in our Community Template and monitor time on whatever page the user is on to redirect to our login screen if the session times out.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the issue.
If there is a login url in the Logout URL and the option below is checked, the issue is gone. I had tested in my sandbox and all is good.
[image]